# Add cross-reference with reference numbers in range in Word

Tags: microsoft-word

Due to convention, if there's a reference with multiple reference numbers in range in an academic paper, it should be `[18-20]` instead of `[18][19][20]`. Likewise, when referencing discretely, what I need is `[18, 21]` instead of `[18][21]`. I've tried to use custom text for cross-reference according to [this instruction](http://www.msofficeforums.com/word/8587-changing-cross-reference-text.html). But this will not solve the problem, since the text will not change if the corresponding paper reference number increases when I insert another paper above.

Is there anyway to fulfil my requirement?

Comment: What type(s) of reference are you trying to fix? (i.e. they look like footnote references, but maybe they are something else). As a general comment, none of WOrd's referencing mechanisms will let you do this automatically which will probably mean that you need to find the manual approach that makes it easiest to maintain the referencing correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get just the number (ie without the square brackets) by editing the cross-reference field after you have inserted it.

Select the cross-reference field and press ALT F9 to view the field code, then at the end before the closing field bracket }, insert

> \# 0

[image]

Then press ALT F9 to revert back to field result, press F9 to update its value, and you should now just see the number (eg 1 not [ 1 ]).

For these reference ranges, you'd need to manually type your opening and closing square brackets, hyphens and commas.