# Add text inside of numbered cross-references in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, cross-reference

I have cross-references to numbered items in a long Word document with the format (1), (2), (3), etc. However, I'd also like to reference items with the format:

(4) a.  example 4a

b. example 4b

c. example 4c

Importantly, I'd like to have a cross reference to have the format (4b), with the letters inside the parentheses.

For now, I've been resorting to the format "(4)b," but this is not ideal.

Some options that I'd be ok with, but can't figure out how to do:

1. Insert a reference without the second paren: "(4" and then add "b) in the text.
2. Insert just the "4", and add both the parentheses and the "b" in the text.
   [Add cross-reference with reference numbers in range in Word](https://superuser.com/questions/1075620/add-cross-reference-with-reference-numbers-in-range-in-word) shows how to do this with brackets; bizarrely, this works only with brackets, and inserts an unwanted dash with parentheses.

Does anyone know how to implement either of the above options?

EDIT: it looks like it works now somehow without the #0 formula (because somehow + * - = +??? anyway). so instead of:

`({ = {REF _Ref452121199 \r \h \# 0 }*-1 }{REF _Ref452121186 \r \h })`

I'm getting the formulas to update with just:

`{ = {REF _Ref452121199 \r \h }*-1 }`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realised there's a way to get rid of negative - at start without using an = field.

Instead, use the switch at the end of the cross-ref field as follows:

```
\# 0;0
```

This extra ;0 at the end sets the format for negative numbers and seems to get rid of that pesky - we were getting with just # 0.

So your xref field for the (4) part should look something like (the _Ref part will be different for your xref):

```
{ REF _Ref452378463 \w \h \# 0;0 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this if you place your number only (eg 4) cross-reference field (with its # 0 switch) inside an = field and multiply it by -1.  The b xref comes in with letter only (ie no .) so nothing to modify there, if it's inserted as (no context) type reference.

```
({ = {REF _Ref452121199 \r \h \# 0 }*-1 }{REF _Ref452121186 \r \h })
```

It's getting a bit complicated, but will yield the result you're after.

Comment: I'm so sorry, every permutation of this I've tried with spaces and brackets gets a syntax error ("!Syntax Error, _REF45205").

I have:

{ = {REF _Ref452054785 \r \h \#0 }*-1 }{ REF _Ref452054785 \r \h }, with the embedded ref inserted by replacing the contents of the original ref, but I get the same error if I just type the brackets in instead.

Is this not the right formula?

Comment: The REF part including its {} should just be the normal cross-reference field (ie I don't type those, to ensure I get the correct hidden bookmark reference for your cross-reference).  Try working in stages for the first one.  Insert an = field first, with a placeholder eg 1*-1.  Outside that field, insert your cross-reference to the numbered heading such as the (4) heading.  Then edit that xref to add the \# 0.  Then cut and paste that edited xref field code and replace the placeholder 1 in your = field.  ALT F9 to switch them all back to field results, select the fields and update with F9.